# Is there a common term for GUI applications that wrap a command-line program?

Tags: user-interface, command-line, scripting, terminology

It happens everywhere with desktop programs and scripts: a GUI application wraps some command-line program to provide a visual experience to its functionality. Is there a common term that describes this kind of GUI application?

I'm looking for a technical one or two-word term, not just "command-line wrapper application," etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A GUI?

> That's a GUI for `xyz`.

Answer (score 7):

"Front-end", maybe?

Comment: Front-ends are usually coupled with the application no? Not a separate wrapper.

Comment: The command-line interface in which it wraps is technically a font-end too though.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most accurate term is "User Interface". The *G* and the fact that there's a command line version behind it are just details.

Comment: The command line tool itself has a user interface. The *G* is important to make this distinction.

Comment: Yes. My point exactly. Both of them are User Interfaces. The G and lack of G are implementation details.

Answer (score 0):

In the airline industry, the term CLF (Common Language Facility) is used.